# Post request with image in body .NET Framwork

Tags: c#

I need to post request to api with image in body. Swagger show it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTe30.png)

and i did request in postman first.
[postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGthR.png)

[postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax6Qc.png)

Now i need to do this in c#.

I have created a void

```
public void addImage(byte[] byteImage,string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                PricerPublicAPIRest api = getAPI();
                using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(byteImage,0,byteImage.Length), name: "image", fileName: filename);
                    content.Add(new StringContent("image/png"), "Content-Type");
                    var unlinkResult = api.SendRequest($"{BASE_URL}file/v1/image", content, new HttpMethod("POST"));
                }
            }
                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeExceptionToLog(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

where byteImage is image in bytes. All i need to know why i have error 500 or bad request when i am posting a photo

Comment: i tried to look how in fiddler or chrome network inspect what i have in body or header my request but when i am sending request then i dont see response in those mods :(

Comment: You are adding two contents but you should only add one. You should add the Content-Type to the ByteArrayContent (it has a Headers Property) and not to a different second content.

Comment: if i have only                     content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(byteImage,0,byteImage.Length), name: "image", fileName: filename);
then still is error 500. How to add this all in one header?

Comment: Don't throw the ByteArrayContent directly directly into the MultipartFormDataContent. Just store it into a variable first and use the properties of that instance then.

Answer (score 0):

Use IFormFile Property in Argument Model class and use [FromForm] before argument this may Resolve issue in both swagger and API Request

```
public class ProjectDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost("FileUpload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload([FromForm] ProjectDetail InpData)
  {
     return Ok("Success");
  }
```

Comment: It is api i am work on not mine to i was able make edit code of it